# Concord with gender-neutral "they"

Tags: grammar, gender-neutral, agreement

I was wondering what the general take is on concord with *they* as a gender-neutral 3rd person singular pronoun. I assume there are no hard and fast rules here yet, seeing that this is a fairly new phenomenon – or am I mistaken here? If there is, indeed, an established rule, please let me know! But if there isn't, what is your view? Do you think grammatical meaning should determine concord (example [1]), or do you think semantic meaning should determine (example [2])?

[1] If someone wants this, they **have** to let us know

[2] If someone wants this, they **has** to let us know

I can't help it – [2] makes me cringe... even though I realise that there are equally good arguments for either.

What's your view? :)

Comment: It’s not uncommon for singular _they_ to align with singular forms (_themself_ is not unheard of, and something like “someone who’d give their life for…” instead of “their lives” is completely standard), but not with actual verbal agreement. _They is/has/does/…_ is, in my experience, completely nonexistent, except of course in dialects where the 3s form is generalised so you’d also say _I is/…_ and _you is/…_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be wrong, but I've never heard "they has" in that context. *Singular they* is not a new phenomenon: see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they) and [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/they) (which has quotes from William Shakespeare and Jane Austen). All the examples I can find with *singular they* have a plural verb: they have, they are, they do.